# Downloaded CSV starts with BACKSPACE and other weird characters

Tags: csv, utf-8, ftp, vb6

I downloaded a CSV (encoded in UTF-8) from an FTP server (using some VB6 code which has always worked in the past) and found it started with `08 00 50 9e` (**`BACKSPACE` `NULL` `P` `ž`** in ASCII).

I've downloaded the same file (a different version) before and never had a problem, so I don't believe the FTP client is at fault here.

Is there some meaning to those characters?
I've tried searching for that string on Google, but (obviously?) did not succeed in the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... it was an issue the VB6 code: instead of `Print #iFileNumber, sFileContents`, it used `Put #iFileNumber, , sFileContents` in **`Binary`** mode instead of **`Output`** mode (no idea why it worked before, but perhaps I changed something without realising it).
`Put` adds a four-byte string length indicator, hence `08 00 50 9e`.

### Problematic code

```
Open App.Path & "\Temp.csv" For Binary As #iFileNumber
Put #iFileNumber, , StrConv(x.Value, vbUnicode)
Close
```

### Working code

```
Open App.Path & "\Temp.csv" For Output As #iFileNumber
Print #iFileNumber, StrConv(x.Value, vbUnicode)
Close
```